# PowerShell Get Users Email Address To Exchange

Tags: powershell, azure

Trying to do an auto ligation hold script using an ad synced group up to Azure. Would anyone be able to help with the below?

I'm trying to get all my users from the MsolGroup by doing a return of the MsolGroupMembers, I would like to return the users then from that I need to get their UPN/Email Address so I can pipe it into an exchange online command to turn litigation hold on for each of them users from the group.

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$user="removed"

$file = "removed"

$password = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString 

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($user,$password)

Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
$UserCredential = Get-Credential -Credential $cred

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session

$usersOfGroup = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId removedID -All


foreach ($user in $usersOfGroup)
{
    $mailbox = Get-Mailbox $user.EmailAddress 

    Write-Output $mailbox

    if ($mailbox.LitigationHoldEnabled -eq $false -and $mailbox.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox")
    {
        Write-Output "Current mailbox: " $mailbox.UserPrincipalName
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox.UserPrincipalName -LitigationHoldEnabled $true -LitigationHoldDuration 2555 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: What part of your code isn't working, and what error are you receiving?

Comment: It's getting the upns out of the group members I'm struggling with to put that into a variable for the set-mailbox command to use

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
    #Useful Microsoft documentation
    #https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn767952(v=exchg.160).aspx

    #Connect to Exchange Online
    Import-Module MSOnline
    $O365Cred = Get-Credential
    $O365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell" -Credential $O365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $O365Session -AllowClobber
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $O365Cred

    #Filter mailboxes for the HR Department, pipe to the set litigation command for 365 days
   Get-Recipient -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter 'Department -eq "HR"' | Set-Mailbox -LitigationHoldEnabled $true -LitigationHoldDuration 365
    Remove-PSSession -Id $O365Session.Id
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for that, helps clear some things up, but playing around with it this seems only for ad attriubtes based on users. We would like to do it based on the AD group or the azure ad synced group. I was leaning more to azure ad group as it returns users UPNs needed to turn the ligation hold on, but more than happy to go with on prem AD group.

Comment: based off this link, we can change the command before the pipe characters to get Group
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996594(v=exchg.160).aspx
Get-Group -Identity "Marketing Reports" | Set-Mailbox -LitigationHoldEnabled $true -LitigationHoldDuration 365

Comment: that only seems to get the group, not the users of the group with their UPNs

Comment: How about the Get-SecurityPrincipal?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298162(v=exchg.160).aspx